# How can I add data in the middle of the row?

Tags: javascript, excel, html-table, datatable, row

The following are my problem with my code:

1. It should be editable in the middle of the data, not just the last.
2. If the data is edited, the BCA total should update for all rows from where the edit occurs up to the last.
3. Data should be deletable, and when new data is input, it should be updated correctly.

Here is my code in function editData and function saveData

```
function editData(button) {
    let row = button.parentNode.parentNode;
    let cells = row.cells;

    // Store the current values before editing
    let editedGross = parseFloat(cells[9].innerHTML.replace(/[^0-9.]/g, '')) || 0;
    let editedBIR = parseFloat(cells[10].innerHTML.replace(/[^0-9.]/g, '')) || 0;
    let editedNet = parseFloat(cells[11].innerHTML.replace(/[^0-9.]/g, '')) || 0;
    let editedReceipts = parseFloat(cells[12].innerHTML.replace(/[^0-9.]/g, '')) || 0;

    // Add the previous values back to the current BCA Total/Balance
   
    currentBcaTotalBalance += editedNet;
    currentBcaTotalBalance -= editedReceipts;

    // Enable content editing
    for (let i = 0; i < cells.length - 1; i++) {
        let cell = cells[i];
        cell.contentEditable = "true";
    }

    button.innerHTML = "Save";
    button.onclick = function () {
        saveData(this);
    };
}

            
function saveData(button) {
    let row = button.parentNode.parentNode;
    let cells = row.cells;

    // Disable content editing
    for (let i = 0; i < cells.length - 1; i++) {
        let cell = cells[i];
        cell.contentEditable = "false";
    }

    // Calculate the new Net
    let newGross = parseFloat(cells[9].innerHTML.replace(/[^0-9.]/g, '')) || 0;
    let newBIR = parseFloat(cells[10].innerHTML.replace(/[^0-9.]/g, '')) || 0;
    let newNet = newGross - newBIR;

    // Calculate the new BCA Total/Balance based on the conditions
    let newBcaTotalBalance;
    if (newNet > 0) {
        // Subtract the new Net from the current BCA Total/Balance
        newBcaTotalBalance = currentBcaTotalBalance - newNet;
    } else {
        // Add the new Receipts to the current BCA Total/Balance
        let newReceipts = parseFloat(cells[12].innerHTML.replace(/[^0-9.]/g, '')) || 0;
        newBcaTotalBalance = currentBcaTotalBalance + newReceipts;
    }

    // Update the table cells with the new values
    cells[11].innerHTML = newNet.toLocaleString('en-US', { minimumFractionDigits: 2, maximumFractionDigits: 2 });
    cells[13].innerHTML = newBcaTotalBalance.toLocaleString('en-US', { minimumFractionDigits: 2, maximumFractionDigits: 2 });
    cells[14].innerHTML =
        '<button onclick="editData(this)">Edit</button>' +
        '<button onclick="deleteData(this)">Delete</button>';

    button.innerHTML = "Edit";
    button.onclick = function () {
        editData(this);
    };
}
```

This first picture is the correct calculation.
(https://i.stack.imgur.com/4UPEg.png)
In this second picture, the 3rd row has been edited, and the BCA total/balance should be 300, and the values in the subsequent rows should also be updated.
(https://i.stack.imgur.com/m4CYh.png)